# getting a specific string fields from a Generic List to an array

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

in c#, let's suppose that i have a class like as follows..

```
public class anItem
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
    }
```

and i use a generic list with that object, like.

```
List<anItem> listof = new List<anItem>();
listof.Add(new anItem { name = "name 1", surname = "surname 1" });
listof.Add(new anItem { name = "name 2", surname = "surname 2" });
listof.Add(new anItem { name = "name 3", surname = "surname 3" });
listof.Add(new anItem { name = "name 4", surname = "surname 4" });
```

is it possible take all surname 's from **listof** generic list to a string array ?

```
string[] takenSurnames = // take just surnames from listof
```

yes i can get that with **foreach** or **for** loops. but i wonder if there's any lambda expression or something like that shorter ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
listof.Select(c => c.surename).ToArray();
```